# How do I align my links in HTML/CSS with the links to be in the same row but on opposite sides?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

```html
<div class="izplav">
  <h1 id="NS">Slavenski Pokret</h1>
  <div class="linkovi">
    <a href="Onama.html" class="link">O nama</a>
    <a href="registracija.html" class="link">Registracija</a>
    <a href="jezik.html" class="link">Jezik </a>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
  #NS {
    font-size: 10x;
    font-family: "Lobster", cursive;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .linkovi {
    color: rgb(255, 175, 2);
    margin-right: 2px;
    text-align: right;
  }
</style>
```

[Problem picture- as you can see it isn't in the same row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEs9d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```css
.izplav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#ns {
  font-size: 10x;
  font-family: "Lobster", cursive;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

.linkovi {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.linkovi a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="izplav">
            <h1 id="NS">Slavenski Pokret</h1>
            <div class="linkovi">
                <a href="Onama.html" class="link">O nama</a>
                <a href="registracija.html" class="link">Registracija</a>
                <a href="jezik.html" class="link">Jezik </a>
            </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use css flex.

```
.izplav {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

If you want to learn more, I recomend this awesome game [Flexbox Froggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com/)